# How do i cast List<dappperrow> to our class?

Tags: dapper

I am new to dapper, I know

```
db.Query<Entity.Account>("Select * From Account").ToList();
```

will do the casting.

Now If I have

```
var ss = db.Query("Select * From Account").ToList();
```

Will rerutn List

how do i cast ss to List ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. DapperRow is a key/value dictionary and cannot be cast to a type. You can only manually declare classes of the desired type using `.Select()`:

```
ss.Select(r => {
   var fields = r as IDictionary<string, object>;
   return new Entity.Account {
      ID = fields["ID"];
      //etc
   };
});
```

The question is: why can't you use the typed `Query<T>()` variant?

Comment: I did. I am just learning boss doing new things

Comment: Can I cast it to list<Entity.Account>

Comment: No, a dictionary cannot be cast to a user type.

Comment: I did invite you in linkedin